# Light not shining on all sides of cube in SceneKit ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I have made a rotating cube with SceneKit and placed it at (0,0,0). I want the cube to be yellow, but I don't want to color the cube yellow. Instead I want a yellow light to shine on the rotating cube. My problem is that only two sides of the cube are yellow, the other 4 sides are black, even if the cubes face is facing the light. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code to create the cube

```
SCNBox *myBox = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:8 height:8 length:8 chamferRadius:0];
SCNNode *myBoxNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:myBox];
myBoxNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:myBoxNode]
```

Here is the code for the light

```
SCNLight *light = [SCNLight light];
light.color = [UIColor yellowColor];
light.type = SCNLightTypeOmni;
SCNNode *lightNode = [SCNNode node];
lightNode.light = light;
lightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 10, 10);
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:lightNode];
```

**EDIT:**

Ok so I found the problem, but no solution. When the cube rotates, its actually not the cube moving but the camera, and the light is fixed to shine on the front face. So since the actual cube is not moving, the other 4 faces do not get exposed to the light. So how can I move the light along with the camera? Or if there is any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the light along with the camera, you will want to add the light to the same node as the camera (either as a child node, or directly by setting the `light` property).

If you are using the default camera (ie you didn't set a camera explicitly in your code), you can access its node through the `pointOfView` property of your `SCNView` ([Apple Developer Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/SCNSceneRenderer/pointOfView)).

Comment: I've done as you said using the default camera, and it works. However, the light type is `SCNLightTypeAmbient` and it does not correlate with my code, which sets the type as `SCNLightTypeDirectional`. Do you know what's going on here? Thank you.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue using the default SceneKit template and indeed, the light is not applied. It seems SceneKit falls back to a ambient light if the `autoenablesDefaultLighting` flag is disabled.

Comment: Yeah. I eventually figured that out. But if you enable it, light will always be coming from the perspective of the camera and it'll have some standard shading.

Comment: Adding the light to a child node of the `pointOfView` doesn't solve the issue either... Maybe a bug ? I believe the default camera controls are here mainly for debug, so the safest solution is probably to setup your own camera, but you will have to handle user-interaction directly...

Note that a Directional light direction doesn't depend on the node position, it is absolute in world space, so the lighting would not follow the camera in this case, according to the documentation.

Comment: That's true - I just meant that the effect is the same (in my case, not sure if it can be generalized) and it's an easier way of thinking about it for me at least

Comment: You're right (I saw your comment after posting the previous one) : it might be possible to access the default omni light and change its settings, this would indeed be a simpler way to get the effect. But it is not associated to the `pointOfView` node, and it doesn't appear in the scene nodes...